# Debug HTML file with inline Javascript in GitHub Codespaces

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, codespaces, github-codespaces

I have created a *.html file with some inline javascript, like the following below:

```js
// noprotect
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            rect(50, 50, 80, 80)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-statistics/7.8.0/simple-statistics.min.js" integrity="sha512-xDFZFTH4OUC3OXrn92+YDyIq7VOQDTSAfcAy2kc9h9Wp/BiGwGVPDCDT2CXy6Aml2j+8AMX98jgdk5gZPcsfbw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="palette"></div>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to debug the file using GitHub codespaces.

I installed the Live Server plugin to run my html file in the browser.

I created the following `launch.json` file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Editor_2",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5502/_ui/editor_v02.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

When running the `Editor_2` configuration I get:

[image]

`Unable to launch browser: "Timed out waiting for browser connection"`

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it is related to [`ritwickdey/vscode-live-server` issue 579](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/579#issuecomment-1144001236), do add [Live Preview - VS Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server), an extension that hosts a local server for you to preview your web projects on.

> Preview your HTML files quickly by clicking the preview button in the top right corner of your editor or using the context menu.
>
> [image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode-livepreview/main/img/open-preview-btn.gif]

Comment: Thx for your reply! How do you debug these files?

Comment: @Carol.Kar I don't know of a breakpoints feature for that kind of file: the "live preview" feature I illustrate in the answer is supposed to help you "debug" your file, since you can see in real time how it is rendered.

Comment: Thx for your reply. True that I can see my file in real time. Still I am looking for a solution to debug my javascript files. Do you have any idea? I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Carol.Kar Any debug/breakpoint operation would need to take place locally, on your computer, *before* pushing it to GitHub. See as an example, with Jekyll, "[Test your Github Pages content locally](https://haralduebele.github.io/2021/02/15/Test-your-Github-Pages-content-locally/)" or "[Testing your GitHub Pages site locally with Jekyll](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/testing-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll)".

Comment: So as a result it is not possible atm to debug html/javascript files via codespaces using breakpoints and the build in debugger of vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

[image: extensons marketplace screenshot]
From the extensions menu, search for and install "LiveServer".

Once installed click on "Go Live" in bottom right hand corner.
[image: Go Live button screenshot]

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! How do you debug a html file? How do you set break points that work?